# Get source video url after uploading video to facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am using Facebook SDK for ios to upload videos, everything works fine and in response it returns Video_ID.

Now I want to get source url of video so I can post it to twitter,

As suggested on facebook developer video page I use following request format to get video details,

https://graph.facebook.com/Video_ID?access_token=Access_Token

In response it return details like video name,picture,thumbnail etc but it wont return "source" tag and its value.

In application FBSession starts with "publish_stream" and "user_videos" permissions.

If I check on Facebook Graph API Explorer tool by creating temporary access token it returns source url, but if i use access token generated after user login in application it won't return source url.

So i would like to know

1. Is i need to make changes in app settings created on Facebook,
2. Is this approach to post Facebook source video url on twitter will work or not.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please help me?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541581/how-to-upload-video-on-facebook-using-the-graph-api-ios

Comment: @user3863537 try answer which is posted on your question