# How to upload video on facebook using the Graph API? (ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm using the latest version of ios and xcode. I've been following this tutorial for sharing video on facebook.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/

But there are some errors in commands like the following two commands are not working.

```
  facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@""];

  [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

what should I do?

Comment: in here add ur Facebook id--facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"123213213421424234"]; this id will particularly identify your app

Comment: the tutorial will explained in clearly , if show in blankly it given the error

Comment: I've added my facebook app id here but its still not working

Comment: u were added the url scheme in .plist

Comment: i added in .plist as well

Comment: what the error u get

Comment: No visible @interface for Facebook declares the selector "initWithAppId :"